# broadcom bcm5880 ubuntu compatibility

Tags: drivers, broadcom, scanner

I have a question about the Broadcom bcm5880 fingerprint scanner. I've been doing some research and I'm mostly  seeing that there is no Linux support for this model (even though every model above and below is supported). But what I don't get is that when I look at the device on Ubuntu's certification site, it shows that this device is contained in a number of certified machines and none of them mention that there is no support in the section where it lists what works and what doesn't. All in all this really isn't a big deal, I only want it working as a gimmick, but I'm just a little confused because what I take away from the Ubuntu certification site is that it does work but every other resource says it doesn't...

Comment: Why not just try with LiveUSB and tell us?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm already running ubuntu 16.04 and can't get the scanner to work. Upon noticing that it wasn't working I then started doing research and came across the certified hardware saying that it is working (or more specifically not saying that it doesn't) and all the posts saying that it doesn't. I'm just confused why Ubuntu's certification website would list it as certified on about 7 or 8 different machines but every other post says there's no support. I've tried using fingerprintGUI and another one i found, fprintd i think it was called with no success

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this device is that it does two things: reading smartcards and handling fingerprint authorization.

The smartcard part works out of the box, hence the Ubuntu certification, but as far as I can tell there is zero support for the fingerprint reader and Broadcom has shown no interest in releasing specs for the device.  This means it won't be supported until someone goes through the trouble of reverse engineering the Windows driver.

Given how tepid the interest is for fingerprint readers on laptops I wouldn't hold my breath.